# Playing Red Alert 2 Yuri's Revenge RA2 with White Boy's Rules Mod Online multiplayer mode

Tags: mods, command-and-conquer-red-alert

I love playing Red Alert 2 Yuri's Revenge with the White Boy's Rules 1.5 MOD.

Two questions on this:

Q1. How can I play online against other human players?
What servers are there and how do I setup this?

Q2. Where can I meet other people online who also play Yuri's Revenge with White Boy's Rules mod?

Answer (score 2):

You will only be able to play (even enter the game lobbies) or people with exactly the same game version as you. The normal servers will work fine for you. I suggest you search the mods' own forums for other users to try and arrange a game.